# How to find the minimum from a matrix in multiple lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, sorting

I have 3 lists of prices:

```
iexMin =  [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
withLimit =  [0.649, 1.298, 1.298, 2.538, 2.596, 2.596, 2.560, 2.560, 0.560, 1.682, 1.682, 2.242, 2.242, 2.242, 2.287, 2.592, 2.388, 2.98, 3.29, 3.299]
beyondLimit =  [0.66, 2.30134, 2.30155, 2.30171, 2.955, 2.51, 2.519, 2.51, 1.749, 1.749, 1.749, 1.745, 1.749, 1.82208, 1.8993, 1.899, 2.29657, 2.29659, 2.29692, 2.30931]
```

I am dividing them into 4 groups of 5 elements and after that sorting them in decreasing order to get the minimum first 4 min values from each list and then get the compare all the min value from all the list:

```
n = 5
a = [iexMin[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexMin), n)]
b = [withLimit[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexMin), n)]
c = [beyondLimit[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexMin), n)]

testList1 = [sorted(block)[:4] for block in a]
testList2 = [sorted(block)[:4] for block in b]
testList3 = [sorted(block)[:4] for block in c]

price1 = [item for t in testList1 for item in t]
price2 = [item for t in testList2 for item in t]
price3 = [item for t in testList3 for item in t]

minRate = [min(price1[i],price2[i],price3[i]) for i in range(len(price1))]
```

output:

```
min rate =  [0.649, 1.298, 1.298, 2.30171, 0.56, 1.682, 2.51, 2.51, 1.682, 1.749, 1.749, 1.82208, 1.899, 2.29657, 2.29659, 2.29692]
```

The only problem with this output is that I am not comparing the whole matrix here. As I stated that at the beginning that I am dividing the lists into 4 blocks of 5 elements, so basically I want to compare the whole block at once and the 5 min values from each block. So expected output will look like this:

```
IEXMin = [[20, 20, 20, 20], [20, 20, 20, 20], [20, 20, 20, 20], [20, 20, 20, 20]]
withinLimit = [[0.649, 1.298, 1.298, 2.538], [0.56, 1.682, 2.56, 2.56], [1.682, 2.242, 2.242, 2.242], [2.388, 2.592, 2.98, 3.29]]
beyondLimit = [[0.66, 2.30134, 2.30155, 2.30171], [1.749, 1.749, 2.51, 2.51], [1.745, 1.749, 1.749, 1.82208], [1.899, 2.29657, 2.29659, 2.29692]]

##Expected Answer##
min rate =  [0.649, 0.66, 1.298, 1.298, 0.56, 1.682, 1.749, 1.749, 1.682, 1.745, 1.749, 1.749, 1.899, 2.29657, 2.29659, 2.29692]
```

So as you can see I actually want to compare the block at a time and get the first 4 min value from each block. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did some extra work and hence made things complex. Here's one way to solve it:

Using your code:

```py
n = 5
a = [iexMin[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexMin), n)]
b = [withLimit[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexMin), n)]
c = [beyondLimit[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexMin), n)]
```

Then,

```py
minRate = [sorted(a+b+c)[:4] for a,b,c in zip(a, b, c)]
minRate = [item for each in minRate for item in each]
print(minRate)
```

Output:
`[0.649, 0.66, 1.298, 1.298, 0.56, 1.682, 1.749, 1.749, 1.682, 1.745, 1.749, 1.749, 1.899, 2.29657, 2.29659, 2.29692]`

The mistake in your original code was that you were comparing the elements at the same index in the three lists (the last line), and then you'd increase the index.

**Update: How does `sorted(a+b+c)` work?**

Firstly, the `a,b,c` in the list comprehension correspond to the blocks of the lists `a`, `b`, `c` that you defined. I just found that reusing `a,b,c` more convenient but I sure could have used better names.

Now that out of the way, the `+` operator actually joins lists together. `[1,1]+[1,1]` will give `[1,1,1,1]`, for instance. So I *concatenate* the blocks into one and then sort them and pick the lowest 4- `sorted(a+b+c)[:4]`.

Word of caution when using numpy: Using `+` operator with numpy arrays will instead add them as vectors. Since here I could infer from your comprehensions that it was not a numpy array, I used the Python list operator `+` to get the desired result.

Comment: hey thank you so much but I just have one doubt, if you could help me in that then that would more helpful. How does that sorted(a+b+c) work? I mean how does that searching the min value from each block?

Comment: I hope the update to the answer clears your doubt :)